# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'divide' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, scope

This program is designed to be fed a number and generate all of it's prime factors.
I had this working without using any functions earlier, but now I am trying to implement them to get more functionality in my program.

```
divide = 2
factors = []

def nextNumber():
    userInput = input("enter a number to generate factors:\n") #
    number = int(userInput) 

    half = (number / 2) 
    halfFixed = int(half) 

    for x in range (0, halfFixed): # make second arg half of user number 
        result = number % divide

        if result == 0:
            factors.append(divide)

        divide +=1

nextNumber()
print (factors)
```

When I try to run it, the input command is read and I can input a number but as soon as I do I get the error, "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'divide' referenced before assignment"
Any help at all would be great thanks.

Comment: Look at some of the questions on the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning to `divide` in your function, making it a local variable:

```
divide +=1
```

Any other use of `divide` before it is first assigned a value will then raise the `UnboundLocal` exception.

If you meant it to be a global, tell Python so with the `global` keyword:

```
def nextNumber():
    global divide

    userInput = input("enter a number to generate factors:\n") #
    number = int(userInput) 

    half = (number / 2) 
    halfFixed = int(half) 

    for x in range (0, halfFixed): # make second arg half of user number 
        result = number % divide

        if result == 0:
            factors.append(divide)

        divide +=1
```

Comment: That's got it working, thanks a lot and sorry if this as a repeated question, I am kinda new to this site.